# Adding a string to a List<string> inside of a List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, list

Im trying to add a string object to a list inside of list> in a for & while loop, trying to use var i as the list object i wish to use.

here is the code of the class, any help on what im doing wrong would be very much appreciated :)

```
public class GenClass
{

    private static int _genCount;
    private static bool _filesLoadedToLists;
    private static List<string> _nounSetOne = new List<string>();
    private static List<string> _nounSetTwo = new List<string>();
    private static List<List<string>> _toLoad = new List<List<string>>();

    private string _emotionMidTrim = "";

    public const string FileOne = "NounSetOne.txt";
    public const string FileTwo = "NounSetTwo.txt";

    public GenClass()
    {
        while (_filesLoadedToLists == false)
        {
            TextToList(FileOne,FileTwo);
            _filesLoadedToLists = true;
        }

        _genCount++;
    }
```

the problem is withing this part of the class

```
    public void TextToList(string fileOne, string fileTwo)
    {
        List<string> filesToRead = new List<string>();

        filesToRead.Add(fileOne); // Add the text files to read to a list
        filesToRead.Add(fileTwo); // Add the text files to read to a list

        _toLoad.Add(_nounSetOne); // Add a list of words to this list
        _toLoad.Add(_nounSetTwo); // Add a list of words to this list

        for (int i = 0; i <= filesToRead.Count; i++)
        {
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(filesToRead[i]))
             {
                 string line;
                 while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                 {
                     _toLoad[i.Add(line)]; // the error is here
                 }
             }
        }
```

Comment: `i` is an integer, so you can't invoke `List` methods on it.

Comment: try `_toLoad[i].Add(line)` where `i` is the index.

Comment: thank you maxbeaudoin! that is what i needed :) im very new to programming and still trying to get the logic down :P

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, with the error, you need to understand that the

> **`List<List<string>>` will take a `List<string>` and NOT A String.**

Try something like this;

```
List<string> listOfString = new List<string>;
for (int i = 0; i <= filesToRead.Count; i++)
{
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(filesToRead[i]))
      {
           string line;
           while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
           {
             listOfString.add(line);
           }
      }
}
```

Then,

```
_toLoad.add(listOfStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using File.ReadAllLines().  Replace the for loop with:

```
foreach(var file in filesToRead) {
  _toLoad.Add(File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList());
}
```

Comment: @DataHead I'm not quite sure what you mean by that? _toLoad is a List<List<string>>. File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList() is a List<string>, so it should add just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut this down considerably using LINQ:

```
List<string> filesToRead = new List<string> {"NounSetOne.txt", "NounSetTwo.txt"};
List<List<string>> _toLoad = new List<List<string>>();
_toLoad.AddRange(filesToRead.Select(f => File.ReadAllLines (f).ToList() ));
```

Note that there's no extraneous variables for the filename (why have FileOne/FileTwo if their only purpose is to get added to a list?) and that we're letting the AddRange take care of creating the `List<string>`s for us automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= filesToRead.Count; i++)
    {
         using (var reader = new StreamReader(filesToRead[i]))
         {
             string line;
             while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
             {
                 _toLoad[i].Add(line);
             }
         }
    }
```